# Typescript does not include package.json file

Tags: javascript, typescript

Whenever I run `tsc` it outputs me the files in JS format, which is working. Except for `package.json`. I need this also inside my output directory. Currently my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],

  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020" /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */,
    "module": "commonjs" /* Specify what module code is generated. */,
    "rootDir": "./" /* Specify the root folder within your source files. */,
    "resolveJsonModule": true /* Enable importing .json files */,
    "outDir": "../src" /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */,
    "esModuleInterop": true /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` for type compatibility. */,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */,

    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    "noImplicitAny": true /* Enable error reporting for expressions and declarations with an implied `any` type.. */,
    "strictNullChecks": true /* When type checking, take into account `null` and `undefined`. */,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true /* When assigning functions, check to ensure parameters and the return values are subtype-compatible. */,
    "strictBindCallApply": true /* Check that the arguments for `bind`, `call`, and `apply` methods match the original function. */,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true /* Check for class properties that are declared but not set in the constructor. */,
    "noImplicitThis": true /* Enable error reporting when `this` is given the type `any`. */,
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true /* Type catch clause variables as 'unknown' instead of 'any'. */,
    "alwaysStrict": true /* Ensure 'use strict' is always emitted. */,
    "noUnusedLocals": true /* Enable error reporting when a local variables aren't read. */,
    "noUnusedParameters": true /* Raise an error when a function parameter isn't read */,
    "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true /* Interpret optional property types as written, rather than adding 'undefined'. */,
    "noImplicitReturns": true /* Enable error reporting for codepaths that do not explicitly return in a function. */,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true /* Enable error reporting for fallthrough cases in switch statements. */,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true /* Include 'undefined' in index signature results */,
    "noImplicitOverride": true /* Ensure overriding members in derived classes are marked with an override modifier. */,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true /* Enforces using indexed accessors for keys declared using an indexed type */,
    "allowUnusedLabels": true /* Disable error reporting for unused labels. */,
    "allowUnreachableCode": true /* Disable error reporting for unreachable code. */,

    /* Completeness */
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking .d.ts files that are included with TypeScript. */,
    "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  }
}
```

As you can see I set `resolveJsonModule` to `true` and it still does not include it.

I have tried to use `include`

```
"include": ["package.json"],
```

But then it ONLY outputs `package.json` inside my output directory and nothing else. So how do I make it work?

Comment: Why exactly do you expect a TypeScript -> JavaScript compiler to copy around JSON files?

Comment: IMO the compiler should only compile. If for some reason you need that particular JSON file in your build output, add an additional npm script or whatever which does the job.

Comment: @JSONDerulo so, does this mean i need to copy it manually?

Comment: I'm not sure... Did you try something like `"include": ["package.json", "src/**/*.js"],`? (depending on your folder structure)

Comment: @JSONDerulo well it works, but i did some changes. This worked for me`"include": ["package.json", "./**/*.ts"],`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this to work by using [`include`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include), but you also need to reference your TypeScript source files:

```json
{
  "include": "package.json", "your-source-directory/**/*.ts"
}
```